# Blazor server App gray out every 60 seconds

Tags: blazor, server-side, reconnect

I have a Blazor server-side app. When I publish the app, When browsing to an arbitrary page and just letting it idle after a minute or so (sometimes only 45 sec, sometimes something between 1 and two minutes), the screen shows a loader sign as follows, and after a few seconds screen backs to its normal state.
[image: Loader sign]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is probably when you temporary lose connection to the server (likely internet issues).

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine, I test the app in the local network with a stable connection.

Comment: Is there an error message in the browser console? (F12, Console tab?)

Answer (score 0):

The Blazor's SignalR connection times out.  You may want to increase the `ClientTimeoutInterval` and `KeepAliveInterval`:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
.AddHubOptions(options =>
{
    options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);
    options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
});
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the above code, but it's not working! Is there any way to disable it?